# JSONP Wordpress ANDROID = fail

Tags: android, jsonp

I needed to access the content of a WordPress page, via JSONP.
I've managed to do it with this pluging in WP: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/
And this code in the HTML page that request the content via JSONP from WP page:

```
 <div id="content"></div>
      <script>

var page_id = 14;

$.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.domain.org/?json=get_page&page_id='+page_id+'&callback=?',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            $("#content").html(data.page.content);
        }
});
```

Now, the problem is that on Android won't load the content, as he wouldn't recognize or accept the script. Why? (ON Desktop it works perfectly)

Comment: Did you run the code in the Android browser or a `WebView`?

Comment: @ Lukas Knuth, I run it on a android device, but is all fixed. Thanks!